# applescript subroutine and action's properties

Tags: applescript

I am stuck with an action properties error with my little applescript. Here's the script:

```
tell application "evernote" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    --tell process "evernote"
    set the clipboard to text_content()
    keystroke "v" using command down
    keystroke return
    --end tell
end tell
return input
end run
```

here's sub-routine after main program

```
on text_content()

delay 1

tell application "Safari" to set theURL to URL of front document
set theDate to do shell script "date +'%d-%m-%Y'' - '%T"
set theusertext to " , "
set get_text to (theURL & return & theusertext & theDate) as string
return get_text

end text_content
```

This is showing me an action properties error. I've tried to define get_text as properties at different places all over the script, but still getting the same error. Any guidance on how to deal with it?

Comment: Running the script you provided verbatim issues no error at all for me, and has the expected behavior. Do you run it directly in the Script Editor? If so, what is your OS version?

Comment: yes, you are correct, I've edit my post. It's problem with different part of the script.

Comment: it can't run sub-routine now. it's in automator, not apple script.

Comment: i've solved it and got it running , but I still don't know why it was not running the sub-routine ??

Comment: A side note for you @lawsome, I would consider removing your "System Events" tell block in favor of working directly in Evernote. No need to do a paste into Evernote. Change your line `set the clipboard to text_content()` to `set yourText to text_content()`. Then `tell application "Evernote"
 set selectedNote to selection -- selected note
 append (item 1 of selectedNote) text yourText
end tell` If you can avoid working with the clipboard it will make for a better user experience in my opinion.

Comment: thank you @throwback point taken, I've spent an entire day & night perfecting my script, it can now append screenshots from different apps with their meta data (urls in case of safari & local file locations in case of other apps). I'm not a programmer or tech guy, but its a little good victory feeling. All credit and thanks goes to stack overflow and googling. I am only 2 days old user of evernote and even if I don't use evernote in future, it was a good experience getting the script done. Thanks, once again to all.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Evernote 6.6.1 (453372) on OSX 10.11.4, executing from either the Scripts menu or from Script Editor.

```
--- GET THE INFO FROM SAFARI FIRST ---

set the clipboard to (text_content() & return)

tell application "Evernote" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "evernote"
        keystroke "v" using command down
        delay 0.5

        --- Evernote is NOT behaving properly ---
        --    It should leave the cursor at the END of the paste
        --    but it is not.
        --    So, we have to arrow down then issue a return
        --    The above delay is also required to make sure the paste
        --    has completed before any more keystrokes

        key code 125 -- DOWN arrow
        keystroke return

    end tell
end tell


on text_content()

    --delay 1       ## don't see any need for this

    tell application "Safari" to set theURL to URL of front document
    set theDate to do shell script "date +'%d-%m-%Y'' - '%T"
    set theusertext to " , "
    set get_text to (theURL & return & theusertext & theDate) as string
    return get_text

end text_content
```

Comment: thank you @JMichaelTX.  I too noticed the cursor problem you mentioned & I used key code  125 using command down  and keystroke return , but it was processing in safari instead of evernote. Since I used append command, no cursor issues.